# Very odd traffic - is it legit?

Tags: ports, network-scanners

While troubleshooting an unrelated network problem, I noticed an interesting pattern on one of our networks for the last few days (at least). Before crying wolf, I wanted to see if somebody here may have seen this pattern before, and whether it is either associated with some known legitimate activity, or with some known malware.

The sysadmin/owner of the system in question did not know one way or the other whether this is legitimate behavior.

Every few hours in irregular intervals, one of our servers is sending out six packets. The packets are mostly sent to well-known ports. Specifically, ports 7, 21, 25, 80, as well as 40000 and 65535. I don't know if there are any responses, as my system doesn't capture that traffic.

What makes me particularly suspicious is that these packets are all sent by UDP, and to the broadcast address, and that the interval between these sequences varies between one and five or so hours. My first amateur interpretation is that this might be malware looking for a vulnerability, and trying to hide its traffic by using well-known ports.

I found this in the logs produced by an nft-backed firewalld on one of our Linux systems. The system the packets originate from is a Windows server (I believe 2016), and the application running on it has no legitimate reason to scan this particular subnet (that could of course be a misconfiguration).

```
May  3 03:46:25 <redacted> kernel: FINAL_REJECT: IN=ens192 OUT= MAC=<redacted> SRC=<redacted>.90 DST=<redacted>.255 LEN=130 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=29690 PROTO=UDP SPT=52667 DPT=65535 LEN=110 
May  3 03:46:25 <redacted? kernel: FINAL_REJECT: IN=ens192 OUT= MAC=<redacted> SRC=<redacted>.90 DST=<redacted>.255 LEN=130 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=29691 PROTO=UDP SPT=52667 DPT=80 LEN=110 
May  3 03:46:25 <redacted> kernel: FINAL_REJECT: IN=ens192 OUT= MAC=<redacted> SRC=<redacted>.90 DST=<redacted.255 LEN=130 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=29692 PROTO=UDP SPT=52667 DPT=25 LEN=110 
May  3 03:46:25 <redacted> kernel: FINAL_REJECT: IN=ens192 OUT= MAC=<redacted> SRC=<redacted.90 DST=<redacted.255 LEN=130 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=29693 PROTO=UDP SPT=52667 DPT=21 LEN=110 
May  3 03:46:25 <redacted> kernel: FINAL_REJECT: IN=ens192 OUT= MAC=<redacted> SRC=<redacted>.90 DST=<redacted>.255 LEN=130 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=29694 PROTO=UDP SPT=52667 DPT=7 LEN=110 
May  3 03:46:25 <redacted> kernel: FINAL_REJECT: IN=ens192 OUT= MAC=<redacted> SRC=<redacted>.90 DST=<redacted>.255 LEN=130 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=29695 PROTO=UDP SPT=52667 DPT=40000 LEN=110
```

Is there a legitimate explanation for this behavior, or is this something to get alarmed about?

Comment: Best to identify the process creating this traffic. Increase the logging of [WFP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fwp/auditing-and-logging). Beware, it can get *very* noisey so consider increasing log sizes during this time.

Comment: Sysmon (Microsoft/Sysinternals) might help you.